# Clean react native project

Tags: react-native, code-cleanup

How to clean react native project?

Is there any way to clean react native project as we can clean xcode project?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 127):

A react-native Project is about one **XCode Project** and one **Android Project**. (for pure js code, there's no need to do clean)

So, what you need would be

Clean Xcode Project with

```
cd ios
xcodebuild clean
```

And then clean Android Project with

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

You can simply write a batch file for it.

Comment: For what it's worth, 'xcodebuild clean' alone didn't work for my iOS project, where I am using a workspace file.

In that case I had to use ...

`xcodebuild clean -workspace [*.xcworkspace file] -scheme [project name]`

If you don't know your file-name/scheme, just look at the first couple output lines in terminal, when running the normal build. It'll say something like:

`info Found Xcode workspace "x.xcworkspace"`
`info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace [etc]`

Second line, use -workspace & -scheme info from there. Cheers

Answer (score 67):

For android project

```
cd android &&./gradlew clean && cd ../
```

For iOS project

```
cd ios && xcodebuild clean && cd ../
```

If you need build clean again and again then add this scripts in the package.json file like this

```
scripts: { 
  "clean:android": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ../",
  "clean:ios": "cd ios && xcodebuild clean && cd ../", 
}
```

Then run for android

```
yarn clean:android
```

And run for iOS

```
yarn clean:ios
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a space between `cd` and `../`

Comment: You forgot clean in iOS on first line

Answer (score 16):

**For Android**

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```

**For IOS**

```
cd ios
xcodebuild clean
```

Comment: When I used `gradlew clean` order to clean my cache, I got an error: `gradlew : The term 'gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet` why?

Comment: @KhalilShakeri Did you cd in to android?

Comment: Can you confirm you have gradle installed by checking the version. Use `cd android/gradlew -v`

Comment: @ Oluwasayo Cannot find path `E:\Projects\ReactNative\TextAnalyser\android\android\gradlew' because it does not exist`

Comment: Looking at your project's source code in your code editor, do you see a gradlew file in your android folder?

Comment: @ Oluwasayo, Yes there is

Comment: @KhalilShakeri use `gradle clean`

Answer (score 5):

Delete node modules and

```
npm ci

react-native link
```

followed by

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 5):

More useful cleaner scripts. Seperating modules cleaning & native cleaning, based on the other great answers:

```
"scripts": {
      "npm:clean": "rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install"
      "yarn:clean": "rm -rf node_modules && yarn cache clean --force && yarn install"
      "android:clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && cd ..",
      "ios:clean": "cd ios && xcodebuild clean && rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods && rm -rf Pods && rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/* && pod cache clean --all && pod deintegrate && pod setup && pod install && cd ..",
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

this script will clean the Android and IOS build cache, then removes node modules and caches, and reinstall the react native project.

```
# rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
cd android && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache
cd ..
cd ios && pod cache clean --all && rm -rf build
cd ..
rm -rf node_modules
yarn cache clean --force
yarn install
cd ios && pod install
```

To reset the iOS simulator and erase all simulator data, focus on the simulator then go to Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings

To reset the Android emulator and erase all data, open Android Studio then goes to menu Tools -> AVD Manager, then click the dropdown menu on the selected simulator and click on wipe data.

Answer (score 4):

[React Native clean-project](https://github.com/pmadruga/react-native-clean-project) is now the best and easiest way to do deal with react-native artifacts and cleanup. Since it's automatically detected by react-native, it becomes its own command in react-native.

```
$ yarn add -D react-native-clean-project
$ react-native clean-project
```

Answer (score 2):

To reset react-native specific cache, run:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

if in package.json you have

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I added the following scripts to my package.json

```
scripts: {
  ....
  "clean:android": "echo 'require(\"child_process\").execSync(\"cd android; ./gradlew clean\", {stdio: \"inherit\"})' | node ",
  "clean:ios": "echo 'require(\"child_process\").execSync(\"cd ios; xcodebuild clean\", {stdio: \"inherit\"})' | node ",
  "clean": "npm run clean:android && npm run clean:ios",
  ....
}
```

now you can **clean android**

```
npm run clean:android
```

**clean ios**

```
npm run clean:ios
```

**clean both**

```
npm run clean
```

Answer (score 0):

**React** and **node** specific cleaning:

Remove `node_modules` to avoid inconsitence which may appear somehow rarely:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

(reinstall if need with `npm` or `yarn`)

Clean `npm` cache if `npm` is used

```
npm cache clean
```

Clean react temp files:

```
rm -rf $TMP/react*
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean the Android Project with:

```
cd android/
gradlew clean
```

Answer (score -15):

remove android folder
run

```
react-native upgrade
```

then

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: It can break your project if you have any customizations inside android project

Comment: I'm sorry for your losses "bro"